# Unable to install Vpython with Anaconda using conda install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, vpython

[image]

I am trying to install Vpython as per instructions on their documentation website but am receiving this error.

I have anaconda3 running on a 64-bit computer.

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Did you try that command with _anaconda prompt_ ?

Comment: You are trying to install `Vpython` on your `root` env that has `python3.5`. Try `conda create -n vpython Vpython`. This will create a new virtual environment. You can use the new virtual environment by running `activate vpython`.

Comment: That created a package error: PackageNotFoundError: packages missing in certain channels: -vpython. Clearly I am a beginner, so I appreciate your help. I posted a pic as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install "classic vpython" and not the newer vpython. Is this what you are intending to do?

The latest version of VPython is vpython 7 and instructions for installing it are found at http://vpython.org/ .

You can install the new vpython with either conda or pip.

Using conda you intall vpython 7 with the following command.

conda install -c vpython vpython

Using pip you can install vpython 7 with this command.

pip install vpython

The "classic vpython" is no longer supported and is not undergoing any further development. The new VPython 7 is what is currently supported. There are some changes between "classic vpython" and the new vpython. See the documentation for the code syntax for VPython 7 and here is a description of the evolution of vpython.

http://vpython.org/contents/announcements/evolution.html

Comment: I should also add that "classic vpython" is only supported on python 2.7.x . Since you are using python 3 , it is incompatible with "classic vpython". You will need to use the new VPython 7 which works on python 3 .

Comment: I got this working using a virtual environment that runs Python 2.7. But that's great, I'll definitely look into Vpython7 so I don't have to do that. Thanks for the advice!0